# jQuery validate form and after the validation do submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have my markupcode like this

```
<div>
  <form action="http://fileaction.com">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="login-email" class="">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="login-password" class="">
    <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login">
  </form>
  </div>
```

In this form I have two fields. One for email and other for password. I want to validate them both. So the condition will be like this
email field will match the email pattern and the password field will check the password in between 6 and 16 characters. 
Once the field will be validate it will redirect to form action. So for that I have made my code like this

```
var emailField = jQuery('#login-form-wrap input#login-email');
  var passwordField = jQuery('#login-form-wrap input#login-password');
  var emailPattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);

jQuery('input#login').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(emailField.val().length > 0  ||   emailPattern.test(emailField) ) {
    emailField.removeClass('error');
  }
  else {
    emailField.addClass('error');
  }
  if(passwordField.val().length > 6  ) {
     passwordField.removeClass('error');
  }
  else {
    passwordField.addClass('error');
  }

});
```

But it is not validating the email pattern and after valid both field it should redirect to form action page on submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
var emailField = jQuery('#login-email');
var passwordField = jQuery('#login-password');
//there is no need to use new RegExp() since you have a regex literal
var emailPattern = /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i;

//since you have an id, don't use the element selector
jQuery('login-form-wrap form').submit(function (e) {
    //problem here prevent the default only if the value is invalid
    //e.preventDefault();
    var valid = true;
    if (emailField.val().length > 0 && emailPattern.test(emailField.val())) {
        emailField.removeClass('error');
    } else {
        //set the valid flag to false if the field is invalid
        valid = false;
        emailField.addClass('error');
    }
    if (passwordField.val().length > 6) {
        passwordField.removeClass('error');
    } else {
        valid = false;
        passwordField.addClass('error');
    }
    //if the flag is false then the form contains an invalid value, so prevent the defuault action of the click
    if (!valid) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Note: Also instead of binding a click handler to the submit button, use the `form`'s [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event handler

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FJ557/)

Comment: It is not matching the email pattern. If you enter any text ie email field it is taking. It is not adding the class error when the email pattern is not matching...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/submit/

It can bind an submit event to your form so you first can do your validation and then continue with the regular submit if everything is well.

Please don't forget the validation from the backend ;)